# Animating a span on button press

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a web portfolio and I would like for the two buttons on the landing page to move up when one of them is pressed to make room for text. For some reason the buttons will not move with my current setup. Any ideas? Heres my relevant code:

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#Name').addClass("animated fadeOutUp")
    $('#options').addClass("slideUp")})})
```

html

```
<div class = "content animated fadeInUp">
                <h1 id="Name">TOM KAIZER</h1>
                <p></p>
                <span id = "options">
                        <button type = "button" class = "button grow"class = 'resume' style = "text-decoration: none; color: black;">Resume</button>
                        <button type = "button" class = "button grow contact" style = "text-decoration: none; color: black;">Contact Me</button>
                </span>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes slideUp{
        from{
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to{
            opacity:1;
            transform: translateY(-20px);
        }
    };
    @-webkit-keyframes slideUp{
        from { top: 0; left: 0; }
        to   { top: 100px; left: 100px; }
    };

    .slideUp{
        animation-name:slideUp;
        -webkit-animation-name:slideUp;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a placement problem. Just place the @keyframes after .slideUp and it will work. To make the buttons actually move, you will need to set the CSS display property.

```css
.slideUp{
        position: absolute;
        animation-name:slideUp;
        -webkit-animation-name:slideUp;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slideUp{
        from{
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to{
            opacity:1;
            transform: translateY(-20px);
        }
    };
    @-webkit-keyframes slideUp{
        from { top: 0; left: 0; }
        to   { top: 100px; left: 100px; }
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "content animated fadeInUp">
                <h1 id="Name">TOM KAIZER</h1>
                <p></p>
                <span id = "options">
                        <button type = "button" class = "button grow"class = 'resume' style = "text-decoration: none; color: black;">Resume</button>
                        <button type = "button" class = "button grow contact" style = "text-decoration: none; color: black;">Contact Me</button>
                </span>
        </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(e){
  $('#Name').addClass("animated fadeOutUp");
  $('#options').addClass("slideUp");
  });
});

</script>
```